Can't run Clojure inside C#
I am new to clojure, and am attempting to run a simple clojure script in a "hello.clj" file in my .Net Core application. I am receiving this error message:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not locate hello.clj.dll, hello.cljc.dll, hello.clj or hello.cljc on load path.'

This is being executed from a controller in my Razor project:
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        RT.load("hello"); // System.IO.FileNotFoundException happens here
        var output = RT.var("code.clojure.example.hello", "output");
        var t = Convert.ToInt32(output.invoke(3, 2));
        return View();
    }

And this is my project, showing where the "hello.clj" file is, and that it is set to copy to the output folder:

Again, this is my very first time doing this, so I am probably missing something simple. I created this test from an example I found here (the answer at the bottom of the post, not the accepted answer):
Calling Clojure from .NET
Can someone tell me what I am missing, or I am going about this entirely wrong? I want to allow my users to execute their own custom clojure scripts in my app.
Thanks

Where is the hello.clj file getting copied to in the output directory? Is it in the same directory as the project executable or is it in a subdirectory called "Controllers"? Is the load() method looking for a file path? If so, you may want to provide an absolute path.

Yes it does look like it is getting put inside a "Controllers" folder in the bin directory. Could that be the issue?

Depends on what the string for the Load method is expecting.

I was able to fix mine by specifying an environment variable in my Program.cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CLOJURE_LOAD_PATH", "Controllers");


Where "Controllers" is the folder where the hello.clj is located. So I guess you can move yours to a specific folder just for .clj files.
I dug into the source code and RT.load function eventually lands in a function called LoadCljScript which throws an error here:
throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("Could not locate Clojure resource on {0}", "CLOJURE_LOAD_PATH"));

Which is looking for an environment variable but doesn't seem to be setting it anywhere.
I used clojure 1.11.0, FYI.
Hope this works for you too!
